pandas kurtosis/skew bug?
I found some wired results from pandas skew/kurtosis. My pandas version is 2.2.2, numpy version is 2.0.0

Difference between scipy and pandas.

a = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,0.00005])

a.kurtosis()
Out[205]: np.float64(0.0)

scipy.stats.kurtosis(a,bias=False)
Out[206]: np.float64(4.999999999999997)


In rolling operation, subsequent data will influence the previous result. d is a DataSeries with time as index. The result at t is different if I use different length of d after t.

d.loc[:t].rolling(24,min_periods=1).skew().loc[t]
Out[214]: np.float64(4.8898633318381295)

d.loc[:t+timedelta(days=92)].rolling(24,min_periods=1).skew().loc[t]
Out[215]: np.float64(4.692266003534232)

d
Out[216]: 
datetime
2010-01-04 09:05:00    0.000000
2010-01-04 09:10:00    1.000000
2010-01-04 09:15:00    0.987781
2010-01-04 09:20:00    0.941785
2010-01-04 09:25:00    0.930955
  
2024-08-16 22:40:00    0.473696
2024-08-16 22:45:00    0.625088
2024-08-16 22:50:00    0.647181
2024-08-16 22:55:00    0.261825
2024-08-16 23:00:00    0.238032
Name: F_downstd_12, Length: 222106, dtype: float64


d.loc[:t].iloc[-24:]
Out[218]: 
datetime
2016-04-21 11:15:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 11:20:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 11:25:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 11:30:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 13:35:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 13:40:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 13:45:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 13:50:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 13:55:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:00:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:05:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:10:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:15:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:20:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:25:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:30:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:35:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:40:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:45:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:50:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 14:55:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 15:00:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 21:05:00    0.000000
2016-04-21 21:10:00    0.000051
Name: F_downstd_12, dtype: float64

The rolling.kurtosis result is much more different !
d.loc[:t+timedelta(days=92)].rolling(24,min_periods=1).kurt().loc[t]
Out[220]: np.float64(-12419.650647074468)

d.loc[:t+timedelta(days=91)].rolling(24,min_periods=1).kurt().loc[t]
Out[221]: np.float64(-2561.6779850060675)

What's wrong with the pandas ?

Pandas: This is the loss of precision when dividing and power two small float.

It seems the float precision issue. But why

scipy can get the right answer ?
If I use rolling.apply(lambda ds: ds.skew()), I can get the right and stable result. I think the rolling performance optimization of pandas causes this issue. But how can I know when should I not use the rolling.skew/kurt ?


Here is the answer to the first example (and yes, you really found a bug):
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.2.2/pandas/core/nanops.py#L1362
This line turns the interim value into 0 when it is less than 1e-14.
Kurtosis is about the 4-th power of differences between mean and values; that's why such little values are not so impossible to have.
This line appears because of this bug:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18044
which itself is about rolling kurtosis and rolling skew!
Also, there are a lot of bug reports in pandas about rolling skew and rolling kurtosis. This one looks very similar to your case, and there is more information in it about its reasons:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47461

this help me a lot, thanks!
